# Can opening a WPF window in a separate thread always lead to a dead-lock?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Consider the following code I use to open a WPF window on its own thread:

```
    private static void ShowOnNewThreadImpl(Func<Window> factory)
    {
        Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {

            // Create our context, and install it:
            var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; //creates a new instance, if required
            var context = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(dispatcher);
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);

            Window w = factory();
        
            // When the window closes, shut down the dispatcher
            w.Closed += (s, e) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
            };
        
            w.Show();
        
            // Start the Dispatcher Processing
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));

        // Set the apartment state
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        // Make the thread a background thread
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        // Start the thread
        newWindowThread.Start();
    }
```

The window I'm creating is a simple custom window (i.e. with .xaml & xaml.cs):

```
public class PopupWindow : Window
{
    public PopupWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The dead-lock occurs because between calls to `DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait` from the original UI thread and from the new thread.

I'm using this to display a progress bar during heavy UI load, so the call stacks of the main thread differ, for example I've had calls to `FindResource` or handling of `CollectionChanged` events. Within the new thread the lock *always* occurs from within `InitializeComponent()`. In any case, the UI will freeze for 60-90s and then (as if gracefully passing a timeout) continue execution.

I've tried various locking and delay techniques incl. `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DisableProcessing()`, but nothing really helped. My impression now is that it could potentially happen any time the main thread and another "UI thread" access the same... well, what exactly?

Looking into the `DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait` method (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) I find this, which I don't quite understand (but at least gives me the feeling that trying out `DisableProcessing` wasn't completely absurd):

```
public override int Wait(IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    if(_dispatcher._disableProcessingCount > 0)
    {
        // Call into native code directly in order to avoid the default
        // CLR locking behavior which pumps messages under contention.
        // Even though they try to pump only the COM messages, any
        // messages that have been SENT to the window are also
        // dispatched.  This can lead to unpredictable reentrancy.
        return MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(waitHandles.Length, waitHandles, waitAll, millisecondsTimeout, false);
    }
    else
    {
        return SynchronizationContext.WaitHelper(waitHandles, waitAll, millisecondsTimeout);
    }
}
```

How can I avoid these issues? Are there restrictions to keep in mind when using several threads to help avoid these issues?

Side note: I've been using this technique for quite a while without any problems. The difference is that before now the extra-thread-window was created very early before any heavy UI lifting was done - and now I'm trying to open yet another in the middle of a lot of UI work. The first window never has and still doesn't cause problems. The second one causes the dead-lock almost always in RELEASE mode and 2 out of 3 times in DEBUG mode.

Comment: Why should someone will ever run the UI in any other thread then the UI-Thread? It is like driving 20m left or right from the road. Somehow possible but why all that trouble?

Comment: @SirRufo having an application with various different threads and a UI that relies heavily on `INotifyCollectionChanged` (which in turn requires `CollectionChanged` to be invoked on the UI thread), can make it hard to avoid a heavy UI load at times - hence an own thread that can continue to process messages while the main thread dispatcher ist busy.

Comment: The key is to throttle the notifications. The eyes of a humans can read about 24 pictures per second, the displays can display 60 to 120 pictures per second. It does not make any sense to try to update in a much higher frequence.

Comment: Async binding is also an option you may try. But you should avoid different UI threads

Comment: You may find https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections.html#how-to-use-it useful

Comment: A short info about async binding https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30203.wpf-asynchronous-data-binding-using-isasync-and-delay.aspx

Comment: UI loading is usually not heavy. What's heavy is data loading. And this is usually offloaded to a background thread or executed asynchronously. You further optimize loading times by enabling UI virtualization and data virtualization. Use the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event to trigger (async) initialization and **do not use the constructor**. If you design your code properly you will *very* likely never have the need to create a second UI thread. Your issue is likely related to how you have configured the STA thread. It must be a *foreground* (main) thread and not a background thread.

Comment: The whole purpose of your stunt is to create a second main thread,. No requirement to mess around with any synchronization contexts. I highly recommend optimizing the performance of your code. Also consider to create the second main thread before you launch any windows and not while the CPU load is maxed out (I personally would rather clean up my code before using or wasting thraed resources to "fix" the problem).

Comment: A thread per window is a bad idea. Been there, done that and hit lots of issues. I would fix the design and use an indeterminate spinner. Alternatively, use an indeterminate spinner in your new window. Just show and close the progress window. Reference no resources external to it, including styling and templates.

Comment: @SirRufo: thanks for your comments! i look into async binding, but i'm afraid it won't help me here. in my case i'm initializing a fully customizable and therefore possibly complex ui during first load - i can understand why the ui thread is struggling (freezing) and has no time to show its progress. yes, i know, freezes should be avoided - but sometimes in snows in april ;o)

Comment: @BionicCode: thanks for the wild mix of advice. i agree, a heavy ui load can very often be avoided - and i'm positive i'll find the opportunity someday, but until then my live project needs a responsive window for "entertaining" the user while he waits.

Comment: @mike well you will invest time to get your threaded window stable instead invest time to get it right? Maybe you can give us a small example what you are doing on initialize that freezes the UI and we can give you an advise to solve this

Comment: ...imagine how glad i was when i at least finally managed to break it down to this size....